# 400 response when sending POST request with JSON body

Tags: java, android

I've been searching this site and others for solutions on making a POST request with a JSON body, but the solutions I've found don't seem to work for me. For reference, here is a successful request I've made using curl from the terminal:

```
curl -I -X POST -H "x-app-id:myID" -H "x-app-key:myKey" 
-H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "x-remote-user-id:0" 
https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise -d '{
 $+  "query":"ran 3 miles",
 $+  "gender":"female",
 $+  "weight_kg":72.5,
 $+  "height_cm":167.64,
 $+  "age":30
 $+ }'
```

My attempts to convert this for an android app led me to volley, and searching around led me to use the following snippet:

```
try {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("query", "ran 3 miles");
    jsonBody.put("gender", "female");
    jsonBody.put("weight_kg", 72.5);
    jsonBody.put("height_cm", 167.64);
    jsonBody.put("age", 30);
    final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();
    String url = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("LOG_RESPONSE", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("LOG_RESPONSE", error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("x-app-id", "myID");
            params.put("x-app-key", "myKey");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("x-remote-user-id", "0");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The API dictates that the data must be sent in the body, which is why I've excluded the getParams function. This snippet seems to work for everybody else on the internet, but I consistently get 400 messages from it. I've also converted the same curl request into a request in postman, and it works great there as well. Does anyone have any insight as to where I went wrong?

EDIT: [Here's a link to the api as requested](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_q-K-ObMTZvO0qUEAxROrN3bwMujwAN25sLHwJzliK0/edit#)

Comment: Can you post the link to the documentation for the API you are using?

Comment: @Dennis Fixed it, sorry!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Must have felt good :)

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, should have clarified...Fixed the post to include API link. Unfortunately still wrestling with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are passing correct id in `x-app-id`and other fields?  Because as per the logs, it says `"x-app-id" = "myId"`
You need to pass the actual id of your application.

> Also,
>   You have already defined the `content-type` inside *`getBodyContentType()`* so don't mention it in **`getHeaders()`** or do the opposite.

And as per [API documentation](https://gist.github.com/mattsilv/d99cd145cc2d44d71fa5d15dd4829e03) , `x-remote-user-id` isn't required. Maybe this is the reason why your request returned an error of 400

Comment: Removing content-type from the parameters and just having it in the body gets me a 200 response, thank you! Now just to make something useful with this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to send out requests.

You would use this method like this.

```
executePost("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise", mRequestBody, API_KEY);
```

Note, for me, as you will see, I have different API keys for a prod env or lower env. So you may not need API_KEY section... but looking at your headers, you will.. :)

```
public static String executePost(String targetURL, String requestJSON, String apikey) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            //Create connection
            URL url = new URL(targetURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //TODO may be prod or preprod api key
            if (apikey.equals(Constants.APIKEY_PREPROD)) {
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", Constants.APIKEY_PREPROD);
            }
            if (apikey.equals(Constants.APIKEY_PROD)){
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", Constants.APIKEY_PROD);
            }
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(requestJSON.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
            connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(requestJSON);
            wr.close();

            //Get Response  

            try {
                is = connection.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                if (connection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                    int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    if (statusCode != 200) {
                        is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
                    }
                }
            }

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if Java version 5+
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also want to make something else clear. This code is used on my local machine, it is not customer facing. The security of the code was not and is not an issue for my use case. Make sure you security store your API keys.

Comment: He is using `volley`. So your answer won't be of any use here :/